# Is Safari falls under which browser category?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, webkit

The Browser Safari falls under Webkit or not? Please do clarify my doubt at the earliest. If it is not falls under the category of Webkit, what steps would I take to write in CSS. I mean the syntax of CSS for Safari Browser Like -moz for Filezilla and -webkit for Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari is webkit based. In fact safari was the first browser to use webkit and the open source it. The -webkit should work.

You can read more here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_(web_browser)
http://www.webkit.org/